# The engine mode serverless you requested is currently unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am making `ServerlessCluster` with cdk.

However this shows the error like  `"The engine mode serverless you requested is currently unavailable"`

I can make serverlss aurora postgres 15.2 from control panel.

Why It doesn't work on cli?

```
const AURORA_POSTGRES_ENGINE_VERSION = rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_15_2;
const RDS_MAJOR_VERSION = AURORA_POSTGRES_ENGINE_VERSION.auroraPostgresMajorVersion.split('.')[0]

const parameterGroup = rds.ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(this, 'ParameterGroup',  `default.aurora-postgresql${RDS_MAJOR_VERSION}`);


const engine = rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({
    version: AURORA_POSTGRES_ENGINE_VERSION,
});

dbCluster = new rds.ServerlessCluster(this, 'Database', {
    parameterGroup,
    engine: engine,
    credentials: rdsCredentials,
    scaling:{
      minCapacity: rds.AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_2, 
      maxCapacity: rds.AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_8, 
    },
    removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    clusterIdentifier: `ol${targetEnv}`, 
    defaultDatabaseName :metaInfo['dbDatabase'], 
    vpc:vpc,
    vpcSubnets:vpc.selectSubnets({ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }),

    subnetGroup:subnetGroup
});
```

Comment: Which CDK version are you on?

Comment: what's `engine` set to? I see the constants being configured but I don't see where `engine` value is set?

Comment: Somehow engine is disappeared , I added engine.

Comment: cdk versionis `$cdk version
2.77.0 (build 06a0b19)`

Comment: What region are you trying to create it in? It’s possible you’re trying to create it in a region that Aurora Serverless Postgres isn’t supported. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6114